# My boss offers me a promotion while I'm interviewing for another job

Tags: resignation, promotion

I am currently interviewing for a company and waiting for an offer.  Should I get the job, I plan to resign immediately from my current job given the required notice period.

The problem is that my boss has just offered me a promotion and it would look terrible (I think?) if I resigned immediately after the promotion.

On the other hand, I'm not sure if I'll get the new job so I wouldn't want my decline to raise any red flags.  (Obviously if I don't get the new job, I'd want to have that promotion or at least continue working at my current job).

What should I do?

Comment: Does the promotion fix any of the reasons as to why you are looking elsewhere? If they have offered a promotion, now is possibly the time to try and resolve issues with the current employer?

Comment: I personally don't think there's a problem with you leaving just after receiving a promotion. It won't look bad , you simply had a better offer and you chose it . unless you've been changing jobs too frequently it won't look bad. But you might want to wait until the second offer is confirmed

Comment: What type of promotion? Is it a position you'd actually want? Is it a promotion where you'd negotiate salary and other perks? Most are. Is it an option to simply stall or do you expect that you could be waiting a few weeks or longer for the other company's offer?

Comment: Take the promotion, its a "**no brainer**".

Comment: I don't see the harm in accepting the promotion and continuing the interviewing process.  Any employer who would hold it against you for leaving after receiving a promotion is probably the kind of employer who would hold it against you for leaving period (and therefore exactly the kind of employer you should want to leave).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You accept the promotion and continue the interview process. Essentially you have an offer in hand and nothing else. You haven't even completed interviewing for another job let alone been made an offer that matches your expectations.

If you decline the promotion and don't get an offer with the other company you've not only hurt your career at your current employer you've knocked back a chance to improve your CV for future applications.